# ExtJS listening for global keystrokes with Ext.KeyMap

Tags: javascript, extjs, keyboard-shortcuts

To polish up an application im developing I am adding keyboard shortcuts for common tasks. I can sue `Ext.KeyMap` to do this like so...

```
var map = new Ext.KeyMap("my-element", {
    key: 13, // or Ext.EventObject.ENTER
    fn: myHandler,
    scope: myObject
});
```

But I want to detect "ss" or "qq" i.e. specific double key strokes of letters. Im not sure how to do this....

My idea is to detect the singular keystroke, add a listener to detect a following key stroke. And to handle the gap between them, set a delayed event that deletes the listener after x amount of time.

Any improvements/suggestions/warnings??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need an additional listener here. Why not store the previous keystroke in a variable (with the timestamp when the keystroke occurred). Then you could just compare the latest keystroke to the previous keystroke. If they are the same, and the timestamp stored is not too far in the past, that's the double key you're after. If the key codes are not the same, or stored timestamp is too old, just update the stored keycode and timestamp with new values.

Comment: I see what you are saying....but having to store every key that is pressed and do a comparison jsut doesnt seem good practise to me. I guess there is no way to detect double strokes other than something like you have suggested...

Comment: Not sure if this was what you meant, but you don't have to store _every_ key, just the last one. Anyways, I guess this approach can seem a little cumbersome, but it should be actually quite simple and short logic to code. Plus the memory timestamp would be very small (just the last keycode and the timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remember all the keys pressed, just the last one. When you think at the double click event, it's similar, but since clicking two times is more popular, it's already implemented for us.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function defineDoubleKeyMap(element, cfg) {
    var repeated, timer;
    return new Ext.KeyMap(element, {
        key: cfg.key,
        fn: function() {
            if (repeated) {
                // when clicked the second time
                // stop timer and call our callback
                repeated = false;
                clearTimeout(timer);
                cfg.fn.call(cfg.scope);
            }
            else {
                // remember we clicked once, forget after delay
                repeated = true;
                // adjust the delay as needed.
                // current 1 sec is probably too long
                timer = (function(){
                    repeated = false;
                }).defer(1000);
            }
        }
    });
}

defineDoubleKeyMap("my-element", {
    key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
    fn: myHandle,
    scope: myObject
});
```

The probem with this code is that pressing quickly <kbd>ENTER</kbd>-<kbd>DELETE</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> will also fire the event as if <kbd>ENTER</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> was pressed. If that's not acceptable, then you have to keep track of all the keypresses - I think you'll have to use `Ext.get("my-element").on("keypress")` for that.